# Powershell attached all file from folder

Tags: powershell

I need to email and attached all file from the folder but no include any sub-folder.
I am getting error
Cannot find an overload for "Add" and the argument count: "1".
At line:11 char:1

- $emailMessage.Attachments.Add($getallfiles)

below is the powershell code.

```
$dir = "C:\Users\myid\Documents\comparsion\src\main\resources\excelfiles\Compare_Result_Files"
$getallfiles = Get-ChildItem "$dir\*.xlsx"
$emailSmtpServer = "mailhub-au.com"
$emailMessage = New-Object System.Net.Mail.MailMessage
$emailMessage.From = "donotreply@company.com"
$emailMessage.To.Add( "myid@company.com" )
$emailMessage.Subject = "Selenium Report"
$emailMessage.IsBodyHtml = $true
$emailMessage.Body = "Test Summary Attached"
$emailMessage.Body = "$getallfiles"
$emailMessage.Attachments.Add($getallfiles)
$SMTPClient = New-Object System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient( $emailSmtpServer ,$emailSmtpServerPort )
$SMTPClient.Send($emailMessage)`
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to loop through the files and add one at a time.

Also the `Attachments.Add()` method requires the full file name, not a FileInfo object. See [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.outlook.attachments.add)

```
foreach ($file in $getallfiles) {
    [void]$emailMessage.Attachments.Add($file.FulllName)
}
```

I would also suggest adding the `-File` switch to `Get-ChildItem` to ensure you only gather files, not folders.